# Downloaded StructureMap but seems to be missing the Log4Net.Dll

Tags: asp.net, log4net, structuremap

I am currently following instructions in a book to develop an application. It asks me to download StructureMap and then move the StructureMap.Dll file and the Log4Net.dll into the bin files. The problem is there doesnt seem to be a Log4Net.dll file in the StructureMap files, the only other dll apart from the StructureMap.dll is the Rhino.Mock.dll. can anyone help?
Thanks
Rachel

Answer (score 1):

StructureMap underwent a bit of an overhaul recently, so it's possible that a dependency on log4net was removed during that process.  In any case, StructureMap does not currently require log4net.  Here's a quick screenshot from Reflector showing as much:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cryptofreak.org](http://cryptofreak.org/~jnmiller/img/sm-log4net.png))</sub>

It might be worthwhile to find out which version of StructureMap the book is referencing and try that one rather than the latest.

Comment: Ahh that would explain it, thanks for your help. there's not much info out there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing the same social networking site too.  Download StructureMap V.1.1 from here, where you will find both the dlls:

http://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/downloads